# In a list of items when clicked on location icon from the list, only related address modal will open using reactjs

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog

In React, I have a list of items and each item of the list have a location icon link that opens a modal and need to show corresponding address.

But for me when I click on the particular location link, opening all modals location modal at the same time and shows the same address in all the modal. I could not find out how to fix it.

My code is below:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import CustomModal from "../../../components/Modal";

const [showLocationPart, setShowLocationPart] = useState(false);
const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState(null);

const handleModel = item => {
  console.log("selectedItem",item);
  setSelectedItem(item);
  setShowLocationPart(true);
};


{data.cdm_provider_actor_roles.map((actorname, index) => {
  return (
    <div key={index} className="flex-shrink-0 m-2 bg-white border rounded-lg">
      <div className="w-1/3 flex justify-end mr-3 relative" key={actorname.provider_id}>
        <span key={actorname.provider_id} 
          className="bg-[#E9F2EF] w-1/3 p-1 justify-center flex rounded-lg text-[#0CA387] font-semibold cursor-pointer"
          onClick={() => handleModel(actorname)}
        >
          {" "}
          <img src={CDMLocationIcon} className="w-4" />
        </span>
        {showLocationPart ? (
          <div key={selectedItem.provider_id} className="absolute top-7 justify-center items-center flex  z-[999p] outline-none focus:outline-none">
            <div className=" mx-0 w-[350px] h-auto shadow-light  rounded-2xl p-4 bg-gray-50">
              <div className="flex">
                <div className="w-1/6">
                  <div className="bg-[#E9F2EF] p-2 ml-2 mr-2 justify-center flex rounded-lg  text-[#0CA387] font-semibold">
                    <img src={CDMLocationIcon} className="w-4" />
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div className="w-4/6 text-xs font-semibold" >
                  <h5>Address:</h5>
                  <p>
                  {selectedItem.cdm_provider.name}
                  </p>

                 <h5 className="pt-3">Opening Hours:</h5>
                  <p>{selectedItem.cdm_provider.working_hours}</p>

                  <p className="pt-3">Ph: {selectedItem.cdm_provider.phone_number}</p>
                  <p>Fax: {selectedItem.cdm_provider.fax}</p>

                  <h5 className="pt-3">Visit:</h5>
                  <p> {selectedItem.cdm_provider.website}</p>
                </div>

                <div
                  className="w-1/6 cursor-pointer justify-end flex"
                  onClick={() => setShowLocationPart(false)}
                >
                  {" "}
                  <img src={CMDCloseIcon} className="w-3 h-3" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        ) : null}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
})}
```

`handleModel(actorname)` is the icon click.

Comment: move {showLocationPart ? ()} out from the map loop, when its true its render data.cdm_provider_actor_roles.length times and you want only 1 instance

Comment: Thank You for your support.Moved the  {showLocationPart ? ()} out from the loop.Now it is working fine.